# AJAX POST to WEB Method not working for me

Tags: javascript, post, webmethod

I coded up just like everybody else on the net but my WebMethod isn't getting hit from the post action. I believe my code is fine but I'll post my code just in case.
I put a breakpoint in the WebMethod, this is how I know it isn't being called.
Any help would be appreciated.

**AXAJ**

```
                var div = document.getElementById(this.id);
                var divid = div.getElementsByClassName("portlet-id");

                varSQL="UPDATE [ToDoTrack] SET [Status] = '" + this.id + "' WHERE [ID] = '" + divid[0].innerHTML + "'";

                var item = {};
                item.status = this.id;
                item.id = divid[0].innerHTML;
                var Data = '{varSQL: ' + varSQL + ' }'

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ToDoTrack.aspx/UpdateDB",
                    data: Data,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response)
                    {
                        window.location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        alert("Status: " + textStatus);
                        alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                    }  
                });
```

**Code Behind**

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static void UpdateDB(string varSQL)
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(varSQL))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem the data object, it's a string not an object
Its not recommended to create the SQL on client side, it's a security flaw unless it's an application

```
//Problem is a string not object
var Data = '{varSQL: ' + varSQL + ' }'


//Solution below

var Data = {'varSQL':  varSQL  };
// Or this
var Data = 'varSQL='+varSQL;
```

Comment: Posting from mobile forgive typos and bad grammar.

Comment: thanks EDC, but even if the string for the SQL was getting passed I would expect the WebMethod to at least be called, which it isn't.

Comment: On the security, I thought it might be a bad idea but I just wanted to test to see if the database was getting updated

Comment: Yes, I have been testing on that too

Comment: Check if the request is being sent under network tab in developer tools. Then we can debug server side

Comment: Nothing showing up on Network. I also did a trace on the SQL Server but the call just isn't getting through.

Comment: How are you calling this function from javascript? Are you calling it after one clicks button? Try to add

Comment: console.log('to check if method is called');

Comment: It gets called after a drop as part of a drag and drop operation. I put an alert in the function to make to it is hitting the event and it is.

Comment: var div = document.getElementById(this.id);
                var divid = div.getElementsByClassName("portlet-id");

                varSQL="UPDATE [ToDoTrack] SET [Status] = '" + this.id + "' WHERE [ID] = '" + divid[0].innerHTML + "'";

                var item = {};
                item.status = this.id;
                item.id = divid[0].innerHTML;
                var Data = '{varSQL: ' + varSQL + ' }'
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

Comment: Forgive too many comments, i hit enter and its sending. Let me type properly on my computer. Give me a moment

Comment: Thanks for trying, is there some config I have to put in place to make it work? I tried adding EnablePageMethods="true" into the ScriptManager on my Master page but that didn't make a difference

Comment: Are you able to see the request being sent from the web page to your server? If no the problem is at client side. Your other code looks ok on server side.

Comment: One more thing, check url! Its relative to the path and not absolute.

Comment: I saw a post about the RouteConfig.cs and set the value settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off; it did the trick. thanks for all your help on this

Comment: Glad it worked. Thanks. Post that answer somewhere might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

The code seemed to work fine but if you have this issue in the future, these are the things I got from the internet that you seem to need for ajax post to work with WebMethods:

Ensure your URL in AJAX is correct

Ensure your json is well formed

Set `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">,` my script manager was in my site.master

Set settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off; in the App_Start>RouteConfig.cs file